# How to find locators in a page which has been created Flutter in Dart language

Tags: java, flutter, selenium, testing, ui-automation

I am trying to write UI tests for pages developed in Dart in flutter framework. I am unable to find locators to automate the web-elements. Can somebody guide how can I get locators so that I can use selenium/playright to interact with webpage.

Comment: See https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/